# Uploading to a http server

Tags: http, ftp, uploading

I am making a website were people can upload their files (Music, Videos, Images, Documents, etc.) so they can access them on their phone, tablet, and any other internet enabled device.

Right now, I have a HTTP server running on Ubuntu so I can display and play files online, but I need to be able to upload files.  Should I have an FTP server on the same machine as the HTTP server, or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing the *web site* you should implement file upload in your web site code (it is slightly different then submitting usual form, e.g. you should use `POST` request and `multipart/form-data` encoding type, `<input type="file">` `HTML` element, you will have to process this data on the server side in your `servlet` or `controller`), but as you didn't provide much infos about your site, I guess the better for you will be draw attention to some kind of `CMS`. They take care of user accounting and content management (`CMS` = `Content Management System`), i.e. uploading files, removing ones.